# Macro works as button but not as UI ribbon

Tags: vba, excel

Ive coded a very simple VBA macro in Excel to highlight rows if there is only one letter in column 1. The code works fine when run from a Form Control Button, but does not run from a custom UI Button in the ribbon (using an eventhandler, ofcourse). Here is the code:

```
Dim counter As Integer
Dim index As String

counter = 1

While Not index = ""
    On Error Resume Next
    index = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(counter, 1).Value

    If Len(index) = 1 Then
        ActiveSheet.Rows(counter).Interior.ColorIndex = 16
    End If

    counter = counter + 1
Wend
```

Any ideas why? I'm assuming it has something to do with not being able to find ActiveWorkBook.

Comment: Have you tried putting it(code) into a module?

Comment: I put it in ThisWorkbook, which works fine with all my other customUI buttons.

Comment: Which I call using onAction="ThisWorkbook.highlight_eventhandler" in the customUI editor @Mukul215

Comment: I don't see any reason that code should be in ThisWorkbook. Move it to a standard module and see if it works.

Comment: @DickKusleika Thank you. that did work. Not sure why. ThisWorkBook has always worked for me prior